# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in web service API

Tags: php, foreach

I'm using PHP code to call Json API, but I'm having Issues loading.

PHP code

```
                $response[$i]['id']=$dataFriend[$i]['id'];
                $response[$i]['name']=$dataFriend[$i]['name'];
                $response[$i]['id']=$id;
                $response[$i]['lastMSGFrom']=$msg_from;
                $response[$i]['lastMSGType']=$type;
                $response[$i]['lastMSG']=$msg;
                $response[$i]['lastMSGTime']=$time;
                $response[$i]['lastSeen']=$dataFriend[$i]['date'];
                $response[$i]['status']=$dataFriend[$i]['status'];
            }
        }
        foreach ($response as $key => $row) {
            $volume[$key]  = $row['lastMSGTime'];
        }
        array_multisort($volume, SORT_DESC, $response);
        array_unshift($response, $userData);
```

Error log

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
PHP Warning:  array_multisort(): Argument #1 is expected to be an array or a sort flag
PHP Warning:  array_unshift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
PHP Warning:  array_multisort(): Argument #1 is expected to be an array or a sort flag
PHP Warning:  array_unshift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

I would appreciate any ideas?

Comment: All the subsequent errors are caused by the first one.

Comment: How is `$response` set? Please, provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Where does `$response` come from? Have you used `json_decode`?

Comment: $response isn't set as an array for some reason

Comment: Maybe you're missing `$response = json_decode($response, true);` (Assuming all `$response` is a json string)